# Skipping of user input by java

Tags: java

So basically i have written a program for school to get a user input of 10 characters and store it into an array, and then sort it out in ascending order using the bubble sort technique. But whenever i execute the code (in blue j environment), the output that comes skips an input every statement and only runs half the times i want it to.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class p19
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(isr);
        char arr[] = new char[10];
        int i ;char plol;
        System.out.println("Enter characters");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = (char)br.read();
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for(int j=1;j<10-i;j++,x++)
            {
                if(arr[j]<(arr[x]))
                {
                    plol = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = plol;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember, newlines are characters too

Comment: thanks! But is there any way i can ignore the newline character or should i just increase the loops iterations?

Comment: Note that your current code would likely work if all the characters were input on the same line

Comment: Oh.., I am sorry. I made a mistake while typing that bit.

Comment: @AxelH not to read `char`s actually, and OP commented on a deleted answer that he couldn't use it.

Comment: @Aaron, where (Edit, Ow ...) ? Well, depending on the inputs, it could be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the user will always input characters separated by line feeds, you can just read the linefeed(s?) characters and discard them :

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    arr[i] = (char)br.read();
    //br.read()  //discards the CR character, only needed on Windows platforms
    br.read()    //discards the LF character
}
```

The code could be made portable by checking what is the [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) if needed.

As commented, your current code could also be considered correct if all characters were to be input on the same line (i.e. `abcdefghij[enter]`).

Comment: how can i get all the input on one line?

Comment: @UrvishRamaiya don't press "Enter" between each character when you input them? I'm not sure I understood your question

Comment: oh, i get it now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`Updated`: according to using fact that reader is mandatory your sources may look like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class p19 {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(isr);
        char[] arr = new char[10];
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter characters");
        while(i < 10) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            for (int x = 0 ; x < line.length() && i < 10 ; x++) {
                char chr = line.charAt(x);
                //accept only viewable symbols:
                if (chr >= 0x30 && chr < 0xA0) {
                    arr[i++] = chr;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Got array: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

        //there are exists simplier sample of bubble sort:
        for(i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.length - 1 - i ; j++) {
                if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    char big = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = big;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

        for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

PS I have added more verbose output for arrays with `Arrays.toString` - you can omit if you shouldn't use such class.

Comment: The thing is, i am not allowed to use scanner for the code i wrote because we are not taught that in school.

Comment: Only `Reader` is acceptable? Is there some another restrictions?